# how to create the option for printing out statements vs executing them in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm looking for a way to create a switch for this bash script so that I have the option of either printing (`echo`) it to stdout or executing the command for debugging purposes. As you can see below, I am just doing this manually by commenting out one statement over the other to achieve this.

Code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

if [ $# != 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: testcurl.sh <localfile> <projectname>" >&2
    echo "sample:testcurl.sh /share1/data/20110818.dat projectZ" >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo /usr/bin/curl -c $PROXY --certkey $CERT --header "Test:'${AUTH}'" -T $localfile $fsProxyURL
    #/usr/bin/curl -c $PROXY --certkey $CERT --header "Test:'${AUTH}'" -T $localfile $fsProxyURL
```

I'm simply looking for an elegant/better way to create like a switch from the command line. Print or execute.

Comment: As soon as you have subshell commands, any method you use is going to break, not to mention any quoted expansions like ${AUTH} will always expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible trick, though it will only work for simple commands (e.g., no pipes or redirection <sup>(a)</sup>) is to use a prefix variable like:

```
pax> cat qq.sh
${PAXPREFIX} ls /tmp
${PAXPREFIX} printf "%05d\n" 72
${PAXPREFIX} echo 3
```

What this will do is to insert you specific variable (`PAXPREFIX` in this case) before the commands. If the variable is empty, it will not affect the command, as follows:

```
pax> ./qq.sh
my_porn.gz  copy_of_the_internet.gz
00072
3
```

However, if it's set to `echo`, it will prefix each line with that `echo` string.

```
pax> PAXPREFIX=echo ./qq.sh
ls /tmp
printf %05d\n 72
echo 3
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The reason why it will only work for simple commands can be seen if you have something like:

```
${PAXPREFIX} ls -1 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
```

When `PAXPREFIX` is empty, it will simply give you the list of your filenames in uppercase. When it's set to `echo`, it will result in:

```
echo ls -1 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
```

giving:

```
LS -1
```

(not quite what you'd expect).

In fact, you can see a problem with even the simple case above, where `%05d\n` is no longer surrounded by quotes.

If you want a more robust solution, I'd opt for:

```
if [[ ${PAXDEBUG:-0} -eq 1 ]] ; then
    echo /usr/bin/curl -c $PROXY --certkey $CERT --header ...
else
         /usr/bin/curl -c $PROXY --certkey $CERT --header ...
fi
```

and use `PAXDEBUG=1 myscript.sh` to run it in debug mode. This is similar to what you have now but with the advantage that you don't need to edit the file to switch between normal and debug modes.

---

For debugging output from the shell itself, you can run it with `bash -x` or put `set -x` in your script to turn it on at a specific point (and, of course, turn it *off* with `set +x`).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" == "--dryrun" ]]; then
    echoquoted() {
        printf "%q " "$@"
        echo
    }
    maybeecho=echoquoted
    shift
else
    maybeecho=""
fi

if [ $# != 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: testcurl.sh <localfile> <projectname>" >&2
    echo "sample:testcurl.sh /share1/data/20110818.dat projectZ" >&2
    exit 1
fi

$maybeecho /usr/bin/curl "$1" -o "$2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
show=echo
$show /usr/bin/curl ...
```

Then set/unset $show accordingly.

Comment: One disadvantage of this methodm is that the quotes will not appear exactly as you had them written out due to them being evaluated by the shell when running echo

Comment: This has some other disadvantages as well, as shown in my answer: Things like `show ls >/tmp/qq` will not act as you expect :-)

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your specific question, but I guess you're trying to see what command gets executed for debugging. If you replace `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` with `#!/usr/local/bin/bash -x` bash will run and echo the commands in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way for "print vs execute" but I know of a way for "print and execute", and it is using "bash -x". See [this link](http://man.ddvip.com/net/iptables-tutorial/x4962.html) for example.